# Why do we have to cast an array to type[] when initialising a pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

We do not cast a string when initialise a pointer:

```
char *string = "Hello World!";
```

However, if I try to define an array explicitly (whatever it is of), the compiler gives me a warning of type incompatibility:

```
char *string = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

Casting to `char[]` works, but I wonder why do we have to cast? Doesn't a compiler see that the initialising value `{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}` is already an array? If we initialise an array like `string[]` the same way, we do not have to cast though. I assume here the compiler sees what the initialising value is, why doesn't it see it when initialising a pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're initializing a pointer, you have to provide a value that's the address of an object, or a null pointer.

`{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}` is not the address of anything. It's the syntax for an initializer list, which can only be used to initialize a variable whose type is an array or structure type.

You haven't actually shown the cast you're talking about, but I assume it's

```
char *string = (char[]){'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

It's not actually a cast, although it uses similar syntax.

An initializer list preceded by an array or structure type in parentheses is called a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal). It creates an anonymous object of the specified type, and the value is that object.

When used with an array, the value decays to a pointer to the first element of the array, just like any other use of an array in r-value context. This allows you to use it as the initializer of a pointer variable.

So it's effectively equivalent to:

```
char temp[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
char *string = temp;
```

except that there's no name `temp` associated with the array.

You don't need this type of syntax when initializing with a string literal, because string literals already construct the array in static memory and evaluate to a pointer to the first element.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223064/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-why-do-we-have-to-cast-an-array-to-type-when-in).

Answer (score 6):

`string` is a pointer, not an array, so it needs an initializer that is a pointer.

The first code snippet is OK because a string literal has array type, and that array decays into a pointer to its first element.

The second is not OK because you're assigning a set of characters to a pointers.  Because `string` is not an array or struct, only the first member of the initializer list is used.  So you have a character constant, which has type `int`, that you're trying to assign to a pointer.

You say it works if you cast.  If you mean this:

```
char *string = (char []){'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

Then what you have is actually a **compound literal** on the right side which has array type, and like the first example an array decays to a pointer to its first member.

Comment: Thanks, but saying the initialising value `{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}` is a set of characters and not an array would've been enough!

Comment: @Kaiyaha An answer to a question is supposed to help not just you but anyone else who might have the same question that finds this post.

Comment: I know, I just thought you didn't quite get what I was asking about. Anyway everything is fine, thanks for the answer, that explained everything

Comment: Well, now I do not understand why would `string[]` interpret `{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}` as an array without casting. Could you give a brief explanation please?

Comment: @Kaiyaha A compound literal is a way of defining a struct or array "in place".  It looks like a cast but is something different.

Comment: Do arrays and pointers interpret a compound literal `{ ... }` differently?

Comment: @Kaiyaha A compound literal has exactly the type you specify for it.  In the case above, that literal has type `char [6]` i.e. an array of `char` of size 6.

Comment: I wonder how the type is defined if I do not specify anything for it and just give it to a variable as it is without casting

Answer (score 1):

Compound literals like {'a'} or {'a', 1} or even {} are meant to be open for future language extensions.

Maybe the compound literal {'a', 1, 'b', 17} will at some point be a valid rvalue for a possible future pure C hashmap's initialization.

The syntax of C does intentionally not assume too much.

C may grow.

Plus, the little bit of compatibility we have with C++ we don't want to entirely be jeopardized by C compilers making assumptions that would make it harder than necessary for C code to still go correctly through a C++ compiler.

C and C++ need to evolve with a lot of regard for each other.

And even the potential future growth of just C itself makes it necessary to not wildly interpret literals as things they *might* reasonably mean in C